# How to connect to a websocket in Android

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am learning how to use `WebSockets` in `Spring boot` with an `Android client`. I picked up `Scarlet by Tinder`, it looks like a great library. My issue though how to call my `websocket` endpoint in scarlet. I already have a working sample `spring boot` project that constantly updates the locations of users, below is the project

Firstly we have our messagebroker `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`

```
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

}
```

Our listener that listens to connections/disconnections as well as page loads

```
@Component

public class WebSocketEventListener {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketEventListener.class);

@Autowired
private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

//method called when user open page in browser
@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
    logger.info("Received a new web socket connection");
}

//method called when user close page in browser
@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
    StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

    String username = (String) headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().get("username");
    if(username != null) {
        logger.info("User Disconnected : " + username);

        //remove user from latest Location Feed
        CommunicationController.latestLocationFeed.remove(username);

        //transmitting current user's latest location feed
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/app/getData", new LocationBean());
    }
}
}
```

And lastly our controller that basically with 1 endpoint that saves and updates all users with new locations that are subscribed to `/app/getData`

```
public static Map<String, LocationBean> latestLocationFeed = new HashMap<String, LocationBean>();

@MessageMapping("/saveLocation") //for saving current user's location in memory
@SendTo("/app/getData") //for transmitting all connected user's latest location 
public List<LocationBean> saveLocation(@Payload LocationBean bean, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    //getting current user's location from web socket
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", bean.getUser());
    logger.debug("\tUser:"+bean.getUser()+" >>> LocationBean:"+bean.toString());

    //unique user wise latest location feed set in-memory hash map
    latestLocationFeed.put(bean.getUser(), bean);

    //converting map to list
    Collection<LocationBean> values = latestLocationFeed.values();
    ArrayList<LocationBean> listOfValues = new ArrayList<LocationBean>(values);
    logger.info("\tPublicLocationFeed:"+listOfValues.toString());

    //send all user's latest location feed
    return listOfValues;
}
```

Using this on the web is very easy, ideally we have `SockJS` and `Stomp`,
We first initialize `SockJS` with our registered endpoint `registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS()` in spring boot like 
`var socket = new SockJS('/ws');`

Then make an instance of `StompClient` from `SockJS` like
```stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);````

And finally connect
`stompClient.connect({}, whenConnected, whenError);`

Once we are connected we can then `subscribe` to our `/app/getData` which updates us with new user locations like 
`stompClient.subscribe('/app/getData', whenMessageReceived);`

And in case we want to send our new location we can do this with the `/app/saveLocation` endpoint like
`stompClient.send( "/app/saveLocation", {}, getLocationBean() );`

And as simple as that we have the web working, my issue is how to do this exact process in Android using scarlet. 
I cannot seem to even get the `URL` right, I always get a connection failed response.
My service looks like this

```
public interface GdaxService {
@Receive
Flowable<WebSocket.Event> observeWebSocketEvent();

@Send
void sendSubscribe(String message);

@Receive
Flowable<String> observeLocationChangedResponse();
}
```

And I implement it like

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    GdaxService scarletGdaxService = new Scarlet.Builder()
            //.lifecycle(this)
            .webSocketFactory(OkHttpClientUtils.newWebSocketFactory(okHttpClient, "ws://localhost:8080/ws/app/getData"))
            .addMessageAdapterFactory(new GsonMessageAdapter.Factory())
            .addStreamAdapterFactory(new RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
            .build()
            .create(GdaxService.class);



    scarletGdaxService.observeWebSocketEvent()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableSubscriber<WebSocket.Event>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(WebSocket.Event event) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current socket connection status: "+event);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection status flowable complete");
                }
            });
    scarletGdaxService.observeLocationChangedResponse()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableSubscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                    txtResponse.setText(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Flowable has completed");
                }
            });
```

Anyone with experience on how to replicate my web implementation in Android can help.